# Python in exe pyinstaller

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

I want to build a python application. I use `pyinstaller` , I execute this command:

```
pyinstaller -F main.py
```

so I get this error (I barely managed to make a screen because the command line immediately closes)

[image]

Please tell me how to solve this.

Comment: I have used the following pyinstaller -F --onefile  --hidden-import=win32timezone main.py, Is python in your system path?

Comment: @Jisson Unfortunately, this did not help. Yes, python in system path